# 'Mapping' the values of a list to variable

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Suppose I have the variable `expr1 = a[n] + b[n]`, and the list `stencil={-1,0,1}`. I want to make a function `f[expr_, stencil_]:= ...` that can give:

`a[n-1] + b[n-1] + a[n] + b[n] + a[n+1] + b[n+1]`.

Basically I want to 'map' the values inside `stencil` to `n` of `expr`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the ideas by@Ben lzd  `Replace[expr1, $_ -> $ + #, {-1}] & /@stencil // Total`

Comment: It would have been much better if you had defined your expression as a function instead: `Total[Function[n, a[n] + b[n]] /@ (n + {-1, 0, 1})]`.

Answer (score 12):

Another approach could be:

```
Total[Thread /@ Map[# + stencil &, expr1, {-1}]]
```

Note that it's slightly faster than the @Syed answer but uses more memory.

Answer (score 8):

Does this work correctly apart from your example?

```
f = Join @@ (# /. Table[sym -> Head[#][sym, i], {i, #2}, {sym, Variables[Level[#, {-1}]]}]) &;

f[expr1, stencil]
(* a[-1 + n] + a[n] + a[1 + n] + b[-1 + n] + b[n] + b[1 + n] *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Total@(expr1 /. n -> n + # & /@ stencil)
```

> a[-1 + n] + a[n] + a[1 + n] + b[-1 + n] + b[n] + b[1 + n]

Answer (score 5):

```
Distribute[{expr1, stencil},List,List,Plus,Replace[#1,n:>n+#2,2]&]

(* a[-1 + n] + a[n] + a[1 + n] + b[-1 + n] + b[n] + b[1 + n] *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
Total@Flatten[Map[Composition[Through, Map[Head, Variables[expr1]]], 
Mean[Level[expr1, {-1}]] + stencil]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.000063, a[-1 + n] + a[n] + a[1 + n] + b[-1 + n] + b[n] + b[1 + n]}*)
```

Comment: I think you want `Total` instead of `Sort`.

Comment: Thanks, bbgodfrey! :)

Answer (score 4):

Outer also works.

```
Outer[#1/.n->n+#2&, List@@(a[n] + b[n]),{-1,0,1}]//
Total//
Total
```

> a[-1 + n] + a[n] + a[1 + n] + b[-1 + n] + b[n] + b[1 + n]

Here is the trick.

```
a[n]-b[n] // FullForm
```

> Plus[a[n], Times[-1, b[n]]]

So the + or - will not affect the result.

Answer (score 3):

Different way:

```
expr1 = a[n] + b[n]
stencil = {-1, 0, 1}
f[ex_, sten_] := Sum[Map[# + tp &, ex, {2}] /. tp -> sten[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sten]}]
```

Then, `f[expr1, stencil]` gives

```
a[-1 + n] + a[n] + a[1 + n] + b[-1 + n] + b[n] + b[1 + n]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = a[n] + b[n];

stencil = {-1, 0, 1};
```

Get variables

```
v = List @@ expr[[All, 0]]
```

> {a, b}

Get index

```
i = expr[[1, 1]]
```

> n

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0 and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
Plus @@ Splice @* Comap[v] /@ Plus[i, stencil]
```

> a[-1 + n] + a[n] + a[1 + n] + b[-1 + n] + b[n] + b[1 + n]